# separate metamask accounts

Tags: metamask

I have a Metamask account on my windows laptop. Now, I want to open a completely separate Metamask account on my iPad and move assets between the two. Can I do this safely without losing my original account?

Comment: It should be possible to have different mnemonic in each device.